# Tag and Element shortcuts - Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, shortcut

Is there a way you can make your own shortcuts for your tags, like if I type in "li" It will automatically put in li type="square" and all I have to do is hit enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to make your own snippets?

Try the **New Snippet** command in the **Tools**-menu and add the following and save it:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<li type="square">${1:Item} ${2:}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>li</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

This will enter an `<li>`-tag in the current file if you type `li` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
You can also add a `<scope>` tag to limit it to HTML-files.

From the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html):

> Snippets can be stored under any package’s folder, but to keep it simple while you’re learning, you can save them to your Packages/User folder

Comment: There's also some tutorial videos [about this topic on tutsplus](https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/#snippets).

Comment: Thanks dbw! That is a great source of information for Sublime Text 2!